# Javascript/CSS Animation displaying text information for a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a CV website that includes my info about my research papers. And I wanted to create an animation where when you click on the button that says "Paper 1" an abstract info box pops-up and tells you the information for the paper.

Likewise when you click on "Paper 2" the abstract info box for that paper pops-up. I am sharing pictures below of what it would look like. I know this type of animation requires either CSS/Javascript. I am using a template of a sample website to create. Any ideas on how to actually do it? I appreciate your help.

```
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tm-gallery-link" data-filter="research_1">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit nav-icon"></i>
                             Paper 1
                        </a>
                    </li>


                        <figure class="effect-honey tm-gallery-item research1">
                            <p > This is a paragraph about my first research paper. Quisque tincidunt, sem rutrum euismod ornare, tortor arcu tempus lorem, accumsan suscipit mauris lorem at lorem. Praesent feugiat mi at tortor tincidunt, ac consequat ante cursus.</p>
                        </figure>
```

**Clicking on Paper 1**
[image]

**Clicking on Paper 2**
[image]

Comment: this question is very abstract, can you show the before you click on either of the papers?
the pop-up animation already exists and you don't need to worry about it too much, you can use jquery to add class dynamically and that will do your job, or if you want this to be more simple, using bootstrap can be very helpful even in the future

Comment: many ways to do this, need to know the before you click on the papers, what will be the height of this webpage, will it stop at the paper1 and paper2 or will it take the entire page and leave a blank white section on the bottom which only shows up when you click on either paper

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following - I've implemented it in pure JavaScript so you don't have to worry about external libraries (you'll have to add your own styling though, but hopefully the mechanism will suffice):

CSS:

```
.hidden {
   display: none
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- control -->
<div>
    <div class="research-paper" id="paper-1">Paper 1</div>
    <div class="research-paper" id="paper-2">Paper 2</div>
    <div class="research-paper" id="paper-3">Paper 3</div>
</div>

<!-- what gets displayed -->
<div class="" id="paper-content-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="hidden" id="paper-content-2">Lorem ipsum 2</div>
<div class="hidden" id="paper-content-3">Lorem ipsum 3</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let tracker = 1; // initially it's the first

// get every occurrence of "research-paper" class and add a 'click' eventListener to it
let researchPaperClass = document.getElementsByClassName('research-paper');

for(var j = 0; j < researchPaperClass.length; j++){
    researchPaperClass[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var currentId = this.id.replace("paper-", "");

        // first, add 'hidden' to the previous class
        document.getElementById("paper-content-" + tracker).className += " hidden";

        // finally, remove 'hidden' from the current clicked one to show it
        document.getElementById("paper-content-" + currentId).className = document.getElementById("paper-content-" + currentId).className.replace(/hidden/gm, "");

        // update the tracker
        tracker = currentId;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Details here][1]

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction()">
                 <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tm-gallery-link" data-filter="research_1">
                        <i class="fas fa-edit nav-icon"></i>
                         Paper 1
                    </a>
                </li>
</div>

<div style="display:none; background-color:yellow" id="myDIV">
                    <figure class="effect-honey tm-gallery-item research1">
                        <p > This is a paragraph about my first research paper. Quisque tincidunt, sem rutrum euismod ornare, tortor arcu tempus lorem, accumsan suscipit mauris lorem at lorem. Praesent feugiat mi at tortor tincidunt, ac consequat ante cursus.</p>
                    </figure>
</div>
```

This should solve it for you..
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

include jquery to your project and this will do the job

```js
$(document).on("click",".tab", function(e){
  //prevent default behaviour of a tag
  e.preventDefault()
  
 //element clicked on
 var clickedTab =  $(this);
  //id of the target content
 var tabContentId = $(this).attr('href')
 
  //remove the active class from all tabs and tab content elements
 $('.tab').removeClass('active')
 $('.tab-content').removeClass('active')
 
  //add the active class to clicked tab and corresponding tab content element
 clickedTab.addClass('active');
 $(tabContentId).addClass('active');
 
})
```

```css
.tab{
 color:#aaa;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5pt 15pt;
}

.tab.active{
color:#fff;
background-color:#839499;
font-weight:bold
}

.tab-content{
display:none
}

.tab-content.active{
display:block
}
```

```html
<!--include jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- first tab active by default -->
<a class="tab active" href="#paper1">paper 1<a>
<a class="tab" href="#paper2">paper 2<a>
<a class="tab" href="#paper3">paper 3<a>

<!-- first content active by default -->
<div class="tab-content active" id="paper1">
content for paper 1
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="paper2">
content for paper 2
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="paper3">
content for paper 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use divs. In this example I use buttons but it should be very easy to make it work with the code you have. Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .page1 {
                display: none;
            }
            .page2 {
                display: none;
            }
            .page1.add {
                display: contents;
            }
            .page2.add {
                display: contents;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <button onclick="page1()">Page1</button>
            <button onclick="page2()">Page2</button>
            <div class="page1">
                <p>info about page 1...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="page2">
                <p>info about page 2...</p>
            </div>
            <script>
                function page1() {
                    document.querySelector('.page1').classList.add('add');
                    document.querySelector('.page2').classList.remove('add');
                }
                function page2() {
                    document.querySelector('.page2').classList.add('add');
                    document.querySelector('.page1').classList.remove('add');
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this solves your problem, anything that you put in the div will disappear and reappear. I have used this simple solution before.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (this is really a simple and general example you can modified as you want):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.paperTrig').forEach((element) => { element.addEventListener('click', function() { if (document.querySelector('.paper.show')) {document.querySelector('.paper.show').classList.remove('show');} this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');});});
```

```css
ul { padding:0; list-style-type: none; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap }
.paper { transform: scale(0); transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out; }
.show { transform: scale(1); }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="paperTrig">Paper 1</button>
    <div class="paper">
      <h1>Paper 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="paperTrig">Paper 2</button>
    <div class="paper">
      <h1>Paper 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="paperTrig">Paper 3</button>
    <div class="paper">
      <h1>Paper 3</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="paperTrig">Paper 4</button>
    <div class="paper">
      <h1>Paper 4</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above code listen to click event on a button with class `.paperTrig`.
When user click on this button a function execute that removes `.show` from an active element (if it exist), and shows the wanted content.

Basically it looks for the [next element sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) of the clicked button and put on it the `show` class.

The CSS animation achieved with the use of `transform` and `transition`.

Answer (score 0):

For this CSS and Javascript are needed. The easiest way and supported by almost all browsers is given below.

Step 1: Edit Your HTML
Add 'onClick' attribute to the links, ie onClick="showContent(1);"
and 'id' attribute to the contents, ie id="research1"

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tm-gallery-link" data-filter="research_1" onClick="showContent(1);">
    <i class="fas fa-edit nav-icon"></i>
    Paper 1
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tm-gallery-link" data-filter="research_2" onClick="showContent(2);">
    <i class="fas fa-edit nav-icon"></i>
    Paper 2
    </a>
</li>
    
<figure class="effect-honey tm-gallery-item research1" id="research1">
    <p > This is a paragraph about my first research paper.</p>
</figure>

<figure class="effect-honey tm-gallery-item research2" id="research2">
    <p > This is a paragraph about my second research paper.</p>
</figure>
```

A numeric value is used in the onClick="showContent(1);" function to identify the clicked link.

Step 2: Add CSS to hide the second content on initial page load

```
<style type="text/css">
    #research1 {display:block; } 
    #research2 {display:none; } 
</style>
```

Step 3: Add the Javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showContent(x) {
    var r1 = document.getElementById("research1");
    var r2 = document.getElementById("research2");
    if(x == 2){                       
        r1.style.display = "none";
        r2.style.display = "block";
    } else {                           
        r1.style.display = "block"; 
        r2.style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
</script>
```